# while deleting a table row, the spinner shows on all rows in the ng-repeat instead of just the one being deleted

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table with a delete method attached to each row in an NG-REPEAT.
I pass the $index, the delete works, table updates perfectly except that the action indicator(spinner) shows on all the rows of the table, not just the one with the delete event.

[image]

this is the delete button as the last cell in the row inside the NG-REPEAT

```
<button class="btn btn--transparent btn--link" ng-if="campaign.status === 'PENDING'" aria-label="Delete" data-click="megAdminCtrl.removeCampaign(campaign.id, $index)" wgu-confirm-click="Are you sure you wish to completely remove the record of this campaign with the id '{{campaign.id}}'?">
    <span ng-show="!megAdminCtrl.isRemoving" class="icon icon--mid icon--inline-before icon--mid--garbage-can"></span>
    <span ng-if="megAdminCtrl.isRemoving"><span class='spinner spinner--inline'></span></span>
      Delete 
</button>
```

this is the ctrl method to delete which calls the srvc

```
self.removeCampaign = function(cId, idx) {               
            self.isRemoving = true;
            campaignSrvc.removeCampaign(cId).then(function(idx) { 
                var index = idx;
                var tempArr = eval(self.campaigns);
                for(var i = 0; i < tempArr.length; i++) {
                    if(tempArr[i].id === cId) {
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(index === -1)
                    $log.log("an error occured");
                self.campaigns.splice(index, 1);
                self.isRemoving = false;
            });
        };
```

"self.isRemoving" is the t/f flag used to show/hide the spinner/icon

I have never had this happen before, not sure how to get the spinner to only show on the one row. There has to be something I'm missing. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: you need to attach isRemoving flag to each row, not to the whole controller.

Comment: care to elaborate @ABOS ?

Comment: delete(row) {row.isRemoving=true;  callBackend.then(row.isRemoving= false;) } , you have to pass row to this callback for each row and use ng-show="row.isRemoving"

Comment: Thank you for that @ABOS. Ill try it out

Comment: If you set this an answer Ill mark it as the accepted one.